# Flow saying "Required module not found" for <Image> sources

Tags: react-native, flowtype

We have an existing React Native project (version 0.22.2) and I'm trying to set up the Flow type checker (version 0.23) on certain files. However, Flow is giving a lot of errors for the `require()`s calls we're using for `<Image>` sources. For example, we have this code in one of our components in Header.js:

```
<Image source={require('./images/nav.png')} style={styles.navIcon} />
```

Which React Native handles fine and it works. However, Flow seems to be trying to treat the `require()` as a regular module require and not finding it, and giving errors like this:

```
Header.js:30
30: <Image source={require('./images/nav.png')} style={styles.navIcon} />
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ./images/nav.png. Required module not found
```

How can I tell Flow to stop giving these errors? I've tried adding `.*/images/.*` to the `[ignore]` section of my `.flowconfig`, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'm curious, 
[Still on latest](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/784#issuecomment-94208658) flow fails to run on a new project for me.  Have you added custom ignore/include rules beyond what's provided out-of-the-box?  Mind sharing it as a gist if this is really the only problem you have?

Comment: I think we're using mostly out-of-the-box settings from "react-native init", yeah.

Comment: And that works...?  Odd.  I get all sorts of errors from node_modules.  Would you be willing to share your .flowconfig in a gist?

Comment: Sorry, I've actually reverted/deleted the version I was using. In any case, at this point we've decided not to use Flow in our React Native project.

Comment: @AdamTerlson - I had to add .*/node_modules/* to [ignore] in my .flowconfig to get anything reasonable from it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `module.name_mapper.extension` option in .flowconfig. For example,

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension= 'png' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/ImageSourceStub.js.flow'
```

which will map any module name ending in `.png` to an `ImageSourceStub` module, as if instead of writing `require('./foo.png')` you had written `require('./path/to/root/ImageSourceStub')`.

In `ImageSourceStub.js.flow` you can do

```
const stub = {
  uri: 'stub.png'
};
export default stub; // or module.exports = stub;
```

so that Flow knows that `require('*.png')` returns a `{uri: string}`.

See also the [Advanced Configuration](http://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html#options) docs.

Comment: Note that I needed to collapse `= 'png'` to `='png'`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real answer besides to say that flow in React Native seems really dodgy today and it would not surprise me if flow just simply doesn't support this usage at all, but I'd love to be totally surprised!

Personally, as a work-around, I'd just add a higher level   component and ignore the flow errors in that file.

```
// Picture.js
// (No @flow tag at top of file)
const Picture = ({ source }) => (
    <Image source={require(source)} />
)
```

Then use `<Picture source="my/path/pic.jpg" />` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, for JPG files, solved with this .flowconfig

```
module.name_mapper='^image![a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+$' -> 'GlobalImageStub'
module.name_mapper='^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.png$' -> 'RelativeImageStub'
module.name_mapper='^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.jpg$' -> 'RelativeImageStub'
```

Comment: for me it doesn't work... I'm getting really frustrated with flow.